# Achieving atomicity with REST api

Tags: api, rest, service

I'm currently designing both the front-end and the back-end of an application. I am however in doubt how it is best to achieve an atomic behaviour without breaking REST principles. Let's say i have a view that mostly updates one resource (i.e. one table in the DB for example gameConfigurations) but based on some user selections, more resources would have to updated as per business requirements. Visually the user has one save button so it is considered as one modification to him. So my question is:

1. Should I combine all the data in one POST request payload and deal with the conditional calls to other services in the updateGameConfigurations service and update the other resources affected by those configurations?
2. Or should I move this business logic in the front-end service layer, where I make the necessary api calls to modify the different resources? In this case it's hard to achieve atomicity as there are n different api calls.

All feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [API composition](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html) to solve the problem when you need to make multiple requests at the same time.